# Compare column from aggregate function to normal column - MYSQL

Tags: mysql

I'm having a problem comparing the result from an aggregate function to a normal field in a MySQL query. If I use `where` I get `total` column not found and if I use `having` I get `base_tax_amount` not found.

```
SELECT entity_id, base_grand_total + base_subtotal as total from sales_order 
having total > base_tax_amount;
```

Could anyone shed some light on this please?

Thanks,

Comment: Share sample data and expected result set.

Comment: If `base_tax_amount` is really a column in `sales_order`, then your query should be working, I think.

Comment: Add `base_tax_amount` to the select column list.

Answer (score 1):

As per the query execution sequence, -

1. From Clause
2. Where Clause
3. Group By clause
4. Having Clause
5. Select Clause
6. Order By clause

Aliases cannot be used in where clause as it executes earlier than select clause. You need below query -

```
SELECT entity_id, base_grand_total + base_subtotal as total
FROM sales_order
WHERE base_grand_total + base_subtotal > base_tax_amount;
```

Also, Is base_tax_amount a column in your `table`?

Comment: Yes, base_tax_amount is a column in the table